# Ionic Framework gulp --cordova "prepare" failed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I want to build project from https://market.ionic.io/starters/nearme
when try to gulp --cordova "prepare", this error always show :

> Error: Hook failed with error code 127: projectname/app/hooks/after_prepare/update_platform_config.js

I have try answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33781082/3167956), but it show same error, anybody can help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to OSX ^M line endings.

Fix:

```
# check if the file has ^M line endings
cat -v FILE-NAME-WITH-ERROR

# fix the file
tr -d '\r' < FILE-NAME-WITH-ERROR > FILE-NAME-WITH-ERROR.fix

# check if problem fixed in resulting file from above
cat -v FILE-NAME-WITH-ERROR.fix

# overwrite original file with fixed file
mv FILE-NAME-WITH-ERROR.fix  FILE-NAME-WITH-ERROR
```

Comment: Or convert the line endings by opening the file in Notepad++, Edit menu > EOL Conversion > Macintosh (CR)